# error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, unicode

While trying to compile the [Maze Generator/Solver in C](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#C) as present in rosettacode in Visual Studio 2010, I am facing issue during compilation.

The following line

```
#   define SPC "　"
wchar_t glyph[] = L""SPC"│││─┘┐┤─└┌├─┴┬┼"SPC"┆┆┆┄╯╮ ┄╰╭ ┄";
```

is throwing an Error

```
1>d:\projects\maze_cpp\maze_cpp\main.cpp(14): error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings
1>          Concatenating wide "" with narrow "?????? ??? ?"
```

Considering my limited knowledge with Unicode, and the unfriendly description of the error in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86888ehe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), I am puzzled about the problem and how to solve it

Comment: it shows even here that your embedded `"SPC"` in your string is not being marked as text so the problem is like hmjd says that you need to escape the `"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `"`s in the wide string literal:

```
wchar_t glyph[] = L"\"SPC\"¦¦¦-++¦-+++---+\"SPC\"?????? ??? ?";
```

EDIT:

I missed the `SPC` macro (as already posted by Luchian and jrok):

```
#define SPC L"  "
wchar_t glyph[] = L"" SPC L"¦¦¦-++¦-+++---+" SPC L"?????? ??? ?";
```

Comment: This compiles, but I doubt it does what he wants. He wants to concatenate SPC which is a define with the other strings.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, yep. I missed the `SPC` macro.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Strange as to Why VC++ has such strict requirement?